# How to prove $|z - z_0|^{-1 + \epsilon}$ is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

This is the question from Stein and Shakarchi Complex Analysis.

> Suppose that $f(z)$ is holomorphic in a punctured disc $D_r (z_0) - \{z_0 \}$. Suppose also that $|f(z)| \leq A |z - z_0|^{-1 + \epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, and all $z$ near $z_0$. Show that the singularity of $f$ at $z_0$ is removable.

My instinct is to use Riemann's theorem on removable singularities and show that $f$ is bounded near $z_0$. My guess is that's why the inequality is given in the question, but $|z - z_0|^{-1 + \epsilon}$ doesn't seem to be necessarily bounded? As a real function at least it definitely isn't if $\epsilon = 0.5$.

Comment: What is your definition of removable discontinuity you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Multiply both sides by $|z-z_0|$ and take the limit as $z$ tends to $z_0$.

Comment: Why does this help?

Comment: part 4 of Riemann's Theorem listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity @airdish

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to show that the function $$z\mapsto \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\:\text{d}w$$ is a holomorphic extension of $f$ where $C$ is a circle with center at $z_{0}$ and contained in the domain. This is similar to the proof given in Stein and Shakarchi's complex analysis textbook. Following the proof, it must be shown that $$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\int_{\gamma_{\delta}}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\:\text{d}w = 0$$ where $z\neq z_{0}$ and $\gamma_{\delta}$ is a small circle of radius $\delta$ with center $z_{0}$. This follows easily from the given condition on $f$.